# Query using contains to reference a cell value results in parse error

Tags: google-sheets-query

Im trying to query results based on cell values, it seems the contains condition results in parse error. What am I doing wrong?

Query:

```
=QUERY(Company_overview!A2:L,"SELECT * WHERE B CONTAINS "&B3&" AND L >= datetime '"&TEXT(today()-B4,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' AND L <= datetime '"&TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' ")")"
```

Image:
[image: Query]

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found an answer to the correct query:

```
=QUERY(Company_overview!A2:L,"SELECT * WHERE B='"&B3&"' AND L >= datetime '"&TEXT(today()-B4,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' AND L <= datetime '"&TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' ")
```